# Decrypt the code and find the text

Tags: cipher

Break the rule of the following code and find the original text.

> 4844026700420337026680789437084266769043634877
>   3123111411311124132311313221113123421112223234
>   1000111001011110010000101001011001010111101101

Comment: hope it wont break easily

Comment: I suspect that it's a formatting issue on the ios app, but the code is actually three lines of text, correct?

Comment: Yes it is three lines of numbers. line1: 48...77 & line2: 31...34 & line3: 10...01

Comment: I've tagged correctly now. Thanks @JoelReyesNoche

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text is: "I am a decryption genius".

> The decryption is based on the [Telephone Keypad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad). The first line gives the key number, the second line gives the letter number and the third gives if you need to consider this letter or not. So basically you just need to decode the letters with '1' in the last line.

Comment: true! also the Zeros will give "this is not the answer"

Comment: Ohh!.. I didn't check for it.. :P
Thanks for telling.